# Code never reached

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have next xsl code:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
       <!--some code here-->
     <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="NAME" />
     </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>        
<xsl:template name="NAME" match="NAME">
  <!--some code here-->
</xsl:template>
```

But template NAME is never reached, e.g. I have empty HTML with `<body></body>`

My XML structure is:

```
<ROOT>
    <MainNode>
        <NAMES>
            <NAME></NAME>
        </NAMES>
    </MainNode>
</ROOT>
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//Name" />
```

or specify node from document root:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="ROOT/MainNode/Names/Name" />
```

Comment: @Ksice: Then try XPath (first option)

Comment: Remember that XPath is case-sensitive. Both of these solutions should work if the casing is corrected.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the scope in which you are calling `apply-templates`. You're in the root template, which means the current context (location within the XML) is the root element. When you use `select` with `apply-templates`, the XPath is based on the current context/location.

In your case, you're applying templates to all `NAME` elements in the root. Since none exist, your `NAME` template is never being called. As was already suggested, the following should work, assuming the structure, spelling, and capitalization are correct in your example:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="ROOT/MainNode/NAMES/NAME" />
```

Alternately, this XPath should work from anywhere in the document, as it behaves like an absolute path starting at the root of the document:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/ROOT/MainNode/NAMES/NAME" />
```